# can you install eclipse plugins with eclim

Tags: eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin, eclim

I have a quick question about the vim plugin eclim. I was wondering whether you can install eclipse plugins with eclim. Sorry if this has been answered before, but google keeps thinking that I'm asking how to install eclim. Thank you for any responses

Comment: I'm not sure Google is the only one confused. What do you mean install them with eclim? There's already a UI for installing plugins.

Comment: This is a silly question; you install Eclipse plugins from Eclipse itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since eclim is a gateway to a headless eclipse installation, using the director might be what you need:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Director_application

Found this over the eclipse forums here: 
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/160495/